# typing the command "chrome.devtools.network" in console tab in chrome dev tools throws an error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to using this function inside the dev tools:

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(request => {
  request.getContent((body) => {
    if (request.request && request.request.url) {
      if (request.request.url.includes('google.com')) {

         //continue with custom code
         var bodyObj = JSON.parse(body);//etc.
          console.log(bodyObj)
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I basically want to take a json response from a site then turn it into an object and do stuff with it,
but it keeps giving me this error :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'network')

From what I understand chrome.devtools should be available for me inside the dev tools but it throws undefined, any idea why?

Thanks!

I tried it from inside the dev tools as it should be done but it gives an error, I also tried using it in other chromium based browser, gives the same error.

Comment: Code run in dev tools is executed in the website's context. You can't access extension-specific api here. Read this https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/devtools/#creating

Comment: Oh I see thanks!, sorry but can I use an already made extension to do this instead of creating one from scratch? if so do you happen to know one?

Comment: You can take a look at this https://requestly.io/